# Why did the id-monster appear as it did?

Tags: forbidden-planet

Was the form of the monster depicted in the crossfire supposed to represent one of the Krell, albeit a rage/primitive version? That may be supported by Morbius pointing out the doorway and head size. If so, why did the subconscious of Morbius bring this up, and not another form? Say, something like a snake or spider. Or, was this the "default" revenge creature created by the Krell machine?  Ideas or theories?

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to find an answer to this question - did the film's producers even consider a back-story for the monster? - but it's a good thought. Perhaps the Krells' imagination machine was designed to create Krell-like icons to carry out its creators' wishes.

Comment: I would conjecture thusly: Morbius had spent *20 years* on Altair IV studying the Krell. A study that was painfully slow, even with his IQ boosted. Just about everyone has suffered "workmares", where a guy works at his job all night in his dreams. After 20 years, I'd imagine the deepest source of his angst and frustration would be the Krell, with Terran creepy crawlies long faded away.

Comment: The only possible place I can think of that one might find a quasi-canonical answer to this question would be the novelization, which includes one chapter of first-person narration by Morbius.  However, I just reread that chapter (although not the whole book), and there is nothing explicit about Morbius' dreams that might provide insight into why his subconscious formed the monster in the way it did.